# Understanding MDC in Android

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

I'm new to MDC and I want to understand below attributes

```
colorPrimary
colorPrimaryVariant
colorOnPrimary
colorSecondary
colorSecondaryVariant
colorOnSecondary
colorSurface
colorOnSurface
colorBackground
colorOnBackground
colorError
colorOnError
```

I want to know which views will take every color and use for what?

Please I want someone to write a good answer and clear.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.